# search grid returns null value for searchString, searchOper and searchField

Tags: jqgrid

i am using **struts2** and **hibernate** from my project and i am using **jqgrid** for data display. 
now i want to redirect the **jqgrid search** window to a link. i already done that by the following code

```
     $(document).ready(function() 
     {
        $("#link1").click(function()
        {
            $("#gridtable").jqGrid ('searchGrid',{multipleSearch:false, 
                multipleGroup: true,
                recreateFilter: true,
                onSearch: function(event,data)
                {
                    document.location.href="jasperPdf";                      
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

my link code is

```
<s:a id="link1">PDF Report</s:a>
```

It's displays the search window properly. but when i click the find button on the search grid window it return the `searchString, searchOper and searchField` values are **null**. so i couldn't make any further operations. please guide me...

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of *advanced searching* (which you have activated by setting `multipleGroup` to `true`) jqGrid is not using the parameters you have mentioned, but it is using `filters` parameter. This parameter will contain an object describing the selected search options, something similiar to this:

```
{
    "groupOp":"OR",
    "rules":[{"field":"a.id","op":"eq","data":"1"}],
    "groups":[
         {
             "groupOp":"AND",
             "rules":[{"field":"a.id","op":"eq","data":"2"}],
             "groups":[...]
         }
     ]
}
```

Of course the object will be serialized into JSON so you need to deserialize it on server side. The fields have following meaning:

- `groupOp` determines which operator should be used between the rules and groups within the scope
- `rules` contains an array of filter rulles
- `field` this is the equivalent of `searchField` for the rule
- `op` this is the equivalent of `searchOper` for the rule
- `data this is the equivalent of`searchString` for the rule
- `groups` contains an array of sub groups

You can read more [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching).

**UPDATE**

You need to add your parameters to the URL you are redirecting for, for example in case  of *single searching* it might look like this:

```
onSearch: function(event,data)
{
    var gridPostData = $("#gridtable").getGridParam("postData");
    document.location.href = "jasperPdf?searchField=" + encodeURIComponent(gridPostData.searchField) + "&searchOper=" + encodeURIComponent(gridPostData.searchOper) + "&searchString=" + encodeURIComponent(gridPostData.searchString);                      
}
```

Comment: now i need not advanced search. so i am using code like this  $("#gridtable").jqGrid ('searchGrid',{
                onSearch: function(event,data)
                {
                    document.location.href="jasperPdf";                      
                }
            }); but now it's also return the same null value.

Comment: @SugunaSs I hope you are not expecting this parameters in your `jasperPdf` as you haven't passed them there in any way.

Comment: @SugunaSs I have update the answer in case you have forgot about that part.

Comment: yes. that is right. i forgot that part. now i got the answer. thank you so much.

Comment: and i have another one doubt.how to do the same thing for advanced search? thank you.

Comment: @SugunaSs The filters roules would be accessible through `gridPostData.filters`. This is an object so if you want to make a GET request (like in your redirect) you would need to call `JSON.stringify()` on it and then `encodeURIComponent()`. Please remember about accepting/upvoting answers, this is how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to populate hidden fields when I came across this related article which helped me find a solution:

```
\$.extend(\$.jgrid.search,{Find:"Filter Results", caption:"RHZ Results Filter",
    onSearch: function() {
        var gridPostData = jQuery("#tablegrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
            \$.each(gridPostData, function(index, value){
                if (index == 'searchField')
                    {\$('#searchField').val(value);}
                else if (index == 'searchString')
                    {\$('#searchString').val(value);}
                else if (index == 'searchOper')
                    {\$('#searchOper').val(value);}
                else {}
             })},
        closeAfterSearch:true,
        odata: [{ oper:'eq', text:'equal'},
            { oper:'cn', text:'contains'},
            {oper:'bw', text:'begins with'},{oper:'ew', text:'ends with'}
            ]
```

});